# Matlab GPU computing to run parallel simulations with non-scalar output

Tags: matlab, gpu, simulation, montecarlo

I would like to use GPU computing to run parallel simulations.  Input is a random vector `X`, and output is a vector of unknown size `Y`.  The following is a working example that illustrates what I would like to do:

```
%% Find roots to a polynomial with random coefficients and randomly truncate this vector.
clear 
clc

% Parameters
Mc = 100;        % number of simulations
p_degree = 1000; % degree of polynomial

% Simulate Data
parallel.gpu.rng(1);
for ii = 1:Mc
    sgpu(ii).f = gpuArray.rand(p_degree,1);  % Structure to be used in arrayfun with GPU
    s(ii).f = gather(sgpu(ii).f); % Structure to be used in arrayfun with CPU
end

% Calculate using CPU
t = tic();
A = arrayfun(@(x)(temp_roots(x.f)), s, 'UniformOutput', false);
time_CPU = toc(t);

% Calculate using GPU
t = tic();
B = arrayfun(@(x)(temp_roots(x.f)), sgpu, 'UniformOutput', false);
time_GPU = toc(t);

% Output times
sprintf( '%1.2fsecs (CPU)', time_CPU)
sprintf( '%1.2fsecs (GPU)', time_GPU)

function [r] = temp_roots(p)
a = roots(p);
b = ceil(rand(1)*size(a,1));
r = a(1:b);
end
```

Computational times are not improved using arrayfun with gpuArray input.  I presume this is because the  handle `'UniformOutput', false` is not permitted with arrayfun and gpuArray input.  Indeed, according to the help file on [arrayfun with GPUarray input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/arrayfun.html), "*operations that change the size or shape of the input or output arrays (cat, reshape, etc.), are not supported*".  Therefore, I presume, `B = arrayfun(@(x)(temp_roots(x.f)), sgpu, 'UniformOutput', false);` is being calculated on the CPU, and hence we do not see a gain in performance.

My questions are these.  Is there a way to use `arrayfun` or another function so that I can run a large number of independent simulations on the GPU?  Is my assertion that `'UniformOutput', false` is not a valid handle for arrayfun when input is a gpuArray true?  Why do I not see a gain in computational performance in the working example -- what is mechanically going on?  When `'UniformOutput', false` is supplied, does Matlab run `arrayfun` on the CPU instead?